# Signing Certificate Request with special rules

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Well, I am not sure if I specified the question correctly.

While I was browsing web, I checked several SSL certificates and noticed that even Root Certificate doesn't have set all attributes of application(or however is it called).

When I created my own CA Certificate it has:

-All rules of issue,

-All rules of applications.

And new certificates signed by this root has:

-All rules of applications.

Cert companies makes another attributes for Class 1, Class 2, EV. Is it possible to set those rules using OpenSSL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about KeyUsage (e.g., code signing or client authentication) then openSSL can add these attributes. Here is an example of creating a CSR (certificate signing request) with specific KeyUsage attributes.

Create a text file called `test.conf` with this content:

```
[req]
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
req_extensions     = v3_user_req

[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                     = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName             = State or Province Name (full name)
localityName                    = Locality Name (city, district)
organizationName                = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
commonName                      = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)

countryName_default             = US
stateOrProvinceName_default     = Utah
localityName_default            = MyOrganization
organizationName_default        = MyDepartment
organizationalUnitName_default  = MyUnitName
commonName_default              = myserver.mydomain.com

[ v3_user_req ]
basicConstraints       = CA:FALSE
keyUsage               = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
nsCertType             = client, server, email, objsign
```

Now run this command:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -config test.conf -keyout hostname.key -out hostname.csr
x509v3_config
```

Your CSR will be in `hostname.csr` and have this `X509v3 Key Usage` section:

```
X509v3 Key Usage:
  Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
```